# Infinite loop in linked list of multiple data

Tags: c

I'm just starting to learn about linked lists C, I wanna read information about a user-specified number of movies from the keyboard, and print them in the order they are read. Why am I getting an infinite loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node 
{
    int year;                        
    char title[30];
    float budget;
    struct node *nextptr;          
}*stnode;

void createNodeList(int n)
{
    struct node *fnNode, *tmp;
    int year, i;
    char title[30];
    float budget;
    stnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(stnode == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("Enter year for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%d", &year);
        stnode->year = year;      
        stnode->nextptr = NULL; 
        tmp = stnode;
        printf("Enter title for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%s", title);
        strcpy(stnode->title,title);      
        stnode->nextptr = NULL;
        tmp = stnode;
        printf("Enter budget for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%f", &budget);
        stnode->budget = budget;      
        stnode->nextptr = NULL; 
        tmp = stnode;

        for(i = 2 ; i<= n; i++)
        {
            fnNode = (struct node *)malloc(n*sizeof(struct node));
            if(fnNode == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Enter year for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%d", &year);
 
                fnNode->year = year;      
                fnNode->nextptr = NULL; 

                tmp->nextptr = fnNode; 
                tmp = tmp->nextptr; 

                printf("Enter title for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%s", title);
 
                strcpy(fnNode->title, title);    
                fnNode->nextptr = NULL;
 
                tmp->nextptr = fnNode;
                tmp = tmp->nextptr; 
            
                printf("Enter budget for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%f", &budget);
 
                fnNode->budget = budget;  
                fnNode->nextptr = NULL; 
                tmp->nextptr = fnNode;
                tmp = tmp->nextptr; 

            }
        }
    }
}
void displayList()
{
    struct node *tmp;
    if(stnode == NULL)
    {
        printf(" List is empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = stnode;
        while(tmp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Year: %d | Title: %s | Budget: %f\n", tmp->year, tmp->title, tmp->budget);    
            tmp = tmp->nextptr;                 
        }
    }
} 

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf(" Input the number of nodes : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    createNodeList(n);
    printf("\n List of movies you entered : \n");
    displayList();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, when I want to free the memory, should I do it in main, or after the loop when I create the list? Thank you!

Comment: Learn the DRY principle == Don't Repeat Yourself.  You have much duplicated code.

Comment: I suggest you sit down with a pencil and some paper. Then use [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the `createNodeList` function, drawing the list as you create it. Draw a box for all `struct node *` variables you have, and use arrows between the boxes for the `nextptr`. Erase and redraw the arrows as you perform operations on them. See if it all makes sense in the end.

Comment: Some obvious problems: you're repeatedly setting `tmp = tmp->nextptr` after populating each and every field in your node. Similarly repeatedly, unnecessarily setting `stnode->nextptr = NULL;  tmp = stnode;`. Also, you're allocating `n` nodes when you should be allocating  1 node.

Comment: @stark I'll try to clean up the code a bit, I just wanted to see why it isn't working in the current state :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are linking `fnNode` to `fnNode` because:

```
printf("Enter year for movie %d : ", i);
scanf("%d", &year);

fnNode->year = year;
fnNode->nextptr = NULL;

tmp->nextptr = fnNode;
tmp = tmp->nextptr;

/* tmp is the same as fnNode here */

printf("Enter title for movie %d : ", i);
scanf("%s", title);

strcpy(fnNode->title, title);
fnNode->nextptr = NULL;

/* fnNode is connected to fnNode here */
tmp->nextptr = fnNode;
tmp = tmp->nextptr;
```

You should:

- Do modifycation of `tmp` only once per node after putting all data to the node.
- Allocate only one element, not `n` element, for one node.

It will be like this:

```
void createNodeList(int n)
{
    struct node *fnNode, *tmp;
    int year, i;
    char title[30];
    float budget;
    stnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(stnode == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("Enter year for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%d", &year);
        stnode->year = year;
        /* don't update tmp here */
        printf("Enter title for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%s", title);
        strcpy(stnode->title,title);
        /* don't update tmp here */
        printf("Enter budget for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%f", &budget);
        stnode->budget = budget;
        /* update tmp after putting all data */
        stnode->nextptr = NULL;
        tmp = stnode;

        for(i = 2 ; i<= n; i++)
        {
            /* allocate for one node, not n nodes */
            fnNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            if(fnNode == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Enter year for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%d", &year);
 
                fnNode->year = year;
                fnNode->nextptr = NULL; 

                /* don't update tmp here */

                printf("Enter title for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%s", title);
 
                strcpy(fnNode->title, title);

                /* don't update tmp here */

            
                printf("Enter budget for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%f", &budget);
 
                fnNode->budget = budget;
                /* update tmp after putting all data */
                fnNode->nextptr = NULL;
                tmp->nextptr = fnNode;
                tmp = tmp->nextptr;

            }
        }
    }
}void createNodeList(int n)
{
    struct node *fnNode, *tmp;
    int year, i;
    char title[30];
    float budget;
    stnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(stnode == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("Enter year for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%d", &year);
        stnode->year = year;
        /* don't update tmp here */
        printf("Enter title for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%s", title);
        strcpy(stnode->title,title);
        /* don't update tmp here */
        printf("Enter budget for movie 1 : ");
        scanf("%f", &budget);
        stnode->budget = budget;
        /* update tmp after putting all data */
        stnode->nextptr = NULL;
        tmp = stnode;

        for(i = 2 ; i<= n; i++)
        {
            /* allocate for one node, not n nodes */
            fnNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            if(fnNode == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Enter year for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%d", &year);
 
                fnNode->year = year;
                fnNode->nextptr = NULL; 

                /* don't update tmp here */

                printf("Enter title for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%s", title);
 
                strcpy(fnNode->title, title);

                /* don't update tmp here */

            
                printf("Enter budget for movie %d : ", i);
                scanf("%f", &budget);
 
                fnNode->budget = budget;
                /* update tmp after putting all data */
                fnNode->nextptr = NULL;
                tmp->nextptr = fnNode;
                tmp = tmp->nextptr;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` [is considered as a bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).